# Is there a standard template for AS3 documentation?

Tags: actionscript-3, documentation, templates

I've seen it used a couple places:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/classreference/

Is this just a coincidence or is it somewhere I can grab? I'd love to use it for a new project I'm working on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most used standard for documenting ActionScript is javadoc, which is a pool of tags to comment your code. Theese information is extracted and turned into some sort of documentation, eg html pages.

To extract theese information there is a number of tools available. ASDoc is a command line tool. Another tool is [Ortelius](http://ortelius.marten.dk), that comes with a simple GUI that might be a little less "scary" for GUI junkies like me.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [asdoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html). It's what the documentation is automatically generated with.